# data repetition in webscraping using xpath

Tags: html, database, google-chrome, xpath, screen-scraping

I have a problem when im trying scraping data, when im looking an specific information
in google chrome browser console, this repeat it seven times and it goes to the next, here is my code

`$x('//div[@class="cs"]/div/text()').map(x=>x.wholeText)`

this code gives me this

```
['CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 
'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 35 (1.4)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 
'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 
'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 269 (7.3)', 'CS 137 (8.5)', 'CS 137 (8.5)'
 ....................
'CS 241 (7.5)', 'CS 241 (7.5)', 'CS 241 (7.5)', 'CS 226 (9.2)', 
'CS 226 (9.2)', …]
```

Just i want this one time
`CS 35 (1.4)` and then this `CS 269 (7.3)` and so.. i dont want it so many times

this web page im scraping https://www.op.gg/summoners/kr/Hide%20on%20bush

I want a code that helps me solve the problem that I put above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your xpath expression to

```
$x('//div[@class="stats"]//div[@class="cs"]').map(x=>x.innerText)
```

Output should be:

```
[ "CS 35 (1.4)", "CS 269 (7.3)", "CS 137 (8.5)", "CS 226 (6.8)", 
"CS 224 (7.7)", "CS 262 (8.7)", "CS 218 (8.8)", "CS 160 (5.6)", 
"CS 252 (9.9)", "CS 239 (7)", … ]
```

Comment: thanks, now it works, but its strange cuz i try to did it in that way before and it didnt work.... maybe i put @class="info" hahaha

Comment: @BenjaminCorrea Yes, you have to be really specific about the elements, the exact class (and other attribute) names and, importantly, their relative position. You'll get the hang of it with time. If we're done, don't forget to accept the answer please.

Comment: yeah, now i see you put "innerText" and u delete "text()" in my xpath, now i cant put this xpath in my python code to read it, i need the sentence "text()" to get that values, my python code just print "[]", ¿how can i solve that?

Comment: @BenjaminCorrea Your question has nothing to do with python. Converting a console command to python may be doable, but is an entirely different question and, as required by Stack Overflow policy, you should post it as a separate question.

Comment: ok ok im sorry, i will try to solve it, thanks for ur answers anyway ¿how can accept the answer? I try to like it but it asks me for 15 reputation

Comment: @BenjaminCorrea To accept an answer "click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in". Don't worry about the upvote - you'll get to 15 reputation soon enough (maybe with the python question!).

Comment: hahahha its done, now i will make the python question... ;)

Comment: @BenjaminCorrea Good to hear. I'll be on the lookout for it. But a heads up: probably not going to be too easy :)

Comment: hahaha thanks!! i try to learn python making projects from my mind, and now i need data to compare it from another data, i can do it by hand but its not the idea hehehe

Comment: i already posted my python question! :)